Handling PayPal payouts in review and testing in sandbox
I'm implementing Payouts API and I'm trying to test and understand the complete flow of the payout.
In the sandbox, I managed to test these flows:

Receiver does not have an account: statuses: pending -> unclaimed -> successful
Receiver has an account: pending -> successful

There are a lot of things that I'm not able to test in the sandbox, so I want to see if there are ways to test it, and if not, what would be the actual status changes in the live environment. To summarize my questions:

How to test a flow in the sandbox where payout ends up in onhold status?
How to test a flow in the sandbox where payout ends up in blocked status?
From which status can payout transition to onhold or blocked status? For example, does it go directly from pending to onhold/blocked, or maybe it goes something like pending -> unclaimed -> held. Basically, did sender already have their funds deducted when this happened? I need to track moving of the funds, but I'm not sure if there was any movement at this point.
In case the PayPal rejects the payout that is in onhold/blocked status, to which status it transitions to? From my understanding payout will go to returned status, but there are also other statuses, like: reversed, refunded, failed.


All payouts start as pending. They are processed in a batch and that's the initial status before they process.
unclaimed->held isn't a thing. Reasons for being unclaimed and reasons for being held don't overlap, and it would be a rare coincidence for a transaction to end up in both states.
Other than unclaimed, the rest of the things you mention are not common statuses that require testing or automated action by you, at least not to begin. Log the API response with such statuses and flag the payout for manual review. Then contact PayPal if you end up having questions, as they will not be of a non-technical nature.
